# how to create new action for listing all data while i am already used show controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my jobs controller

```
def index
  @job = Job.new
end
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)
 if @job.save
  flash[:notice] = "resume is uploaded"
  redirect_to @job
 else
  flash[:notice] = "resume is not uploaded"
  redirect_to blogs_path
 end
end

def list
  @jobs = Job.all
end
def messages
 @pages = Page.all
end
def show
 @job = Job.find(params[:id]) 
end
def new
 @post = Post.new
end
```

My error is if i will search jobs/list,it will take list is a id.that means id='list'.why it does not take the list is action.

my confif/routes.rb
     `resources :jobs do
       collection do
         get ':list' :as => 'list'
       end
     end`

This also i added but is not working

get 'jobs/list'

---

get 'list' :as => 'list' is not working.And also i have used double models(Job,Post) in single controller that also error,later i will post that issue.so first tell me the above question.I hope u guys

Comment: Try with `get 'list' :as => 'list'`.

Comment: Why are you doing `@post = Post.new` in your `JobsController.new` action? And why are you doing `@job = Job.new` in your `JobsController.index` action? It looks to me like you've fundamentally misconceptualized the standard REST actions. You might want to think on that.

Answer (score 0):

In routes add like this

```
resources :jobs do
   collection do
       get 'list'
    end
 end
```

and run rake routes to see what it is showing for list action and use that